# Mix Effects Survival modeling (coxme)

Tags: mixed-model, survival, random-effects-model, cox-model

I have some experimental data looking at arsenic toxicity in mice and I'm trying to screen for potential biomarkers that associate with survival. I sampled mouse microbiome communities at 2 time points (baseline and 7 days of arsenic exposure). I'm trying to test if the relative abundance of any bacterial taxa are associated with increased or decreased hazard in the mice.

My mixed effects model looks like this:

coxme(Surv(time, ind) ~ taxon + (1|mouse))

where 'mouse' represents the individual mouse, accounting for multiple sampling events.

Am I using the appropriate random effect (individual mouse) to account for multiple sampling events? Or, do I need to include the sampling day variable as a model term?

It seems like this would be the appropriate model in a Linear ME model. Just not sure if that holds for coxme models or not.